# Need help writing a descrambling method for substitution cipher

Tags: java, decoding

I need some help on a Java assignment.  We are given a scrambled text file, which was scrambled using a substitution cipher, where every letter in the text is simply swapped out for another letter.  My program is almost finished, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the final "descramble" method, which takes the scrambled text and replaces each letter with its correct substitute in order to reveal the correct text.

These are the instructions provided in the assignment:

> The descrambling is done by using the letter in the scrambled text as the index in the char array. For example, if the scrambled text has a letter B, you replace it with the character it index 2 in the array. All whitespace and punctuation from the original file should also be in the descrambled file, only the letters should have been changed. Additionally, if a letter was capitalized in the original file, it should be capitalized in the descrambled file (similarily, lowercase letters should still be lowercase).

I'm not asking to have the answer given to me, since this is for school.  I just can't seem to properly understand these instructions, what exactly is it that I need to do to successfully decode the text? Mostly, I don't understand how I can use a letter as an index for a char array, aren't indexes always integers?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what language you're working in, so I'll use C/Java.  You'll want to compute an integer index.  Assume for the moment that `scrambled_char` is an upper case letter then it's:

```
// index into descrambling array:
int index = scrambled_char - 'A' + 1;
```

This has value 1 for character A, 2 for B, etc. as the problem says.  It sounds like you're being given the descrambling array.  For example:

```
char descramble[] = "_ZYX ... ";
```

This would cause A to be translated to Z, B to Y, C to X, ...

The descrambled character will be

```
char descrambled_char = descramble[index];
```

Now you just need to work out how to handle lower case letters, white space, and punctuation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm working with Java. I've edited the first post to include that.  I'm not familiar with C at all, does it work the same as Java?

Comment: The code would be the same for Java.  If you have strings, convert to character arrays with `char [] scrambled = scrambled_string.toCharArray();`